# My SharedPreferences disappear when I do remove some keys in Android

Tags: java, android

I store some user info, and if it's first time launching the app in SharedPreferences. When user logs out, I remove keys which hold the user info. However, when I do that, it also removes the key where I hold the boolean for app launch for some reason. Why that happens? Source:

On app start:

```
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        if (prefs.getBoolean("isFirstLaunch",true)){
            editor.putBoolean("isFirstLaunch",false);
            editor.apply();
            Intent intentIntro = new Intent(this,TutorialActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentIntro);
        }
```

On logout:

```
        SharedPreferences newPrefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor neweditor = newPrefs.edit();

        neweditor.remove("authKey");
        neweditor.remove("forget");
        neweditor.apply();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LandingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: try .commit() it is asynchronous

Comment: seems like your code that above must working fine, so maybe the problem is in another place? did you use your SP in another place of code?

Comment: On the face of it I can't see an issue, I'd think, as already mentioned using .commit() might solve the issue. I'll assume that your app all runs in the same process, if not that could be an issue as SharedPreferences is not process safe.

Comment: I don't think your two removes remove the isFirstLaunch. It is more a problem if the isFirstLaunch is saved in the first place.

Comment: I tried commit to see same results. I will check if its saved.

Comment: Checked it, it is indeed saved, but deleted on logout.